# C# SOAP Service config issue

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, policy

I want to connect a soap web service. I added web references in my project but I had a error which is call "Policy Falsified". I tried a lot. I checked my config file. I check binding and endpoint names etc. Why do I get this error "Policy Falsified"? This is my code. Thanks

This is binding and endpoint codes;

```
  <binding name="ServiceSoap">
     <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/> 
     <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
     </security>
    </binding>

 <endpoint address="https://xxxxxxx.com/api/xxxxxxxxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="AkbankTestSW.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
```

This is client side code;

```
ServiceSoapClient client= new ServiceSoapClient();  
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxxxx";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxxxx"; 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

//params include username&password

```
try
{ 
    var resp= onlineDBS.LimitSorgu(params);  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's far from a [Mre] with so little of the _web.config_. But you do have something weird: The address is in Https but binding is `binding="basicHttpBinding"` Do you have a behavior that enable the HttpsGet? 
WCF configuration schema is really powerfull yet a bit complicate.
Btw did you try with a soap ui to see if the error is consitent?

Comment: You can perhaps add information about your try: did you try in simple http with no security? Did the service work before hand? Have you try simply with ssl with client credential none? Help us locate the issue. Your code in the question look consistent: `clientCredentialType="UserName"` and using `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName`. But you mention "*//params include username&password*", when those should be in the header with `ClientCredentials.UserName`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond.  Yes I've tried with soapui, it works. In VisualStudio, I use the same service link but its not working. And also I changed  the credentials as `clientCredentialType="None"` or  `clientCredentialType="Basic"` and etc. But I didn't try to enable behaviour HttpGet. How can I do it?  Note: this is not MVC project, It's console app

Comment: BasicHttpBinding only supports transport security mode, I see you set the message security mode for BasicHttpBinding in the configuration file, you need to delete it.